# Saving User foreign key upon creation of related model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My `Category` model is related to `User`, but I can't find a way to store the logged in user's id into `user_id` field in `Category`.

`Category` **`models.py`**:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
```

**`views.py`**:

```
class CategoryList(APIView):
    ...
    def post(self, request):
        """
        Create a new Category
        :param request:
        :return: Category
        """
        user_id = request.user.pk
        serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I can access `request.user.pk` and see it's correctly shown, but I can't figure out how I can store this value when creating a new category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add current user id to new record you can pass current user as [`save`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) argument:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(user=request.user)
```

Or you can change serializer and use [CurrentUserDefault](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

```
user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

from docs:

> A default class that can be used to represent the current user. In order to use this, the 'request' must have been provided as part of the context dictionary when instantiating the serializer.

So to use CurrentUserDefault you need to pass request to serializer in view:

```
serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
```